# How to fix' type error decimal module' in python

Tags: python, integer, decimal

I am making a random number generator, but I came across a coding error

I had tried to amend the error and check on a few solutions, but they do not work out

```
from decimal import Decimal
import random
def Random(num1,num2):
random_list=[random.randint(num1,num2)for i in range(num2)]
random_number=(random.choice(random_list))
randomer_number=random.choice(random_list)
print("The two numbers are",str(random_number),"and",str(randomer_number))
```

I expect a random number generation but there is a type error, where 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: you don't use `Decimal()` in your code so how do you get this error?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: I will guess: `num2` is `Decimal` and `range(num2)` gives problem. Try to use `int(num2)` in code `range( int(num2) )` to convert it

Comment: Sorry, however, I need both num1 and num2 to be in Decimal, hence  may I know how I can prevent such error while keeping both num1 and num2 in Decimal?

Answer (score 0):

> 'decimal.Decimal' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

What isn't clear here? Just use `range(int(num1))` instead of `range(num1)`

I think you want something like

```
from decimal import Decimal
import random


def Random(num1,num2):
    random_list=[random.randint(num1, num2)for i in range(int(num2))]
    random_number=(random.choice(random_list))
    randomer_number=random.choice(random_list)
    return random_number, randomer_number

r1, r2 = Random(Decimal(1), Decimal(100))
print(f"The two numbers are {r1} and {r2}")
```

It works without any errors

Comment: Can you show the code which produces the error? That one you show in post isn't a python code at all - you lost indents, you don't call function Random() at all, etc..
I've added my gues to the answer

Comment: Sorry, however I tried the code again and there are no errors. Guess I made a mistake somewhere and thank you for the solution!